# Drivers for wifi card Atheros AR928X - Find and install

Tags: wireless, drivers, atheros

I am new in Ubuntu and I had a big trouble with wifi. My ubuntu 12.10 doesn't detect my wifi card and I can't toggle the "activate wireless" option on the tasks bar (it is grey). I searched for drivers to make it work, but nothing worked for me. Can anyone give me a hand?
Many thanks in advanced!

**lspci** output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500/5100 Series]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8057 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
0c:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
0c:03.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
0c:03.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
```

**lshw -c network** output

```
  *-network               
   descripción: Ethernet interface
   producto: 88E8057 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   fabricante: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
   nombre lógico: eth0
   versión: 10
   serie: 00:24:be:83:b2:4f
   tamaño: 100Mbit/s
   capacidad: 1Gbit/s
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.123 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   recursos: irq:45 memoria:d3520000-d3523fff ioport:c000(size=256) memoria:d3500000-d351ffff
  *-network DESACTIVADO
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       fabricante: Atheros Communications Inc.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlan0
       versión: 01
       serie: 2c:81:58:e6:b6:03
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-18-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       recursos: irq:17 memoria:d2100000-d210ffff
```

**rfkill list all** output

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**lsmo** output

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 37380  0 
bnep                   17707  2 
bluetooth             183121  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             31968  0 
ppdev                  12817  0 
binfmt_misc            17260  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31423  1 
coretemp               13168  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
microcode              18209  0 
serio_raw              13031  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    63356  1 
r592                   17707  0 
memstick               15842  1 r592
lpc_ich                16925  0 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25382  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51255  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_hda_intel          32515  5 
snd_hda_codec         111547  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
uvcvideo               71277  0 
videobuf2_core         32070  1 uvcvideo
snd_pcm                80163  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
videodev               95841  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12756  1 uvcvideo
ath9k                 130464  0 
videobuf2_memops       13184  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
sony_laptop            44183  0 
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mac_hid                13037  0 
mac80211              470382  1 ath9k
ath9k_common           13783  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              393767  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
snd                    61991  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_seq_device,snd_timer
ath                    19187  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
radeon                820703  3 
cfg80211              183966  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
soundcore              14599  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14036  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
video                  18847  0 
ttm                    75534  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         45271  1 radeon
compat                 14557  8 rfcomm,bnep,bluetooth,ath9k,mac80211,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw,cfg80211
drm                   230463  5 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 radeon
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40753  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_generic            12445  0 
usbhid                 41702  0 
hid                    82142  2 hid_generic,usbhid
firewire_ohci          35521  0 
firewire_core          57492  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12627  1 firewire_core
sdhci_pci              18155  0 
sdhci                  27830  1 sdhci_pci
sky2                   52926  0
```

Comment: did you tried `Addtional Drivers` in ubuntu? search for it in dash. If it is unable to get the driver. Post result of `lcpci`, `lshw -c network` and `rfkill list all`

Comment: Hi, additional controllers tab is in blank.
The result of lspci: http://pastebin.com/Cqe6BA11
The result of lshw -c network: http://pastebin.com/q0BuC1VY
The result of rfkill list all: http://pastebin.com/wXw3XiDw

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Need some more info. Can you post result of `lsmod`? also make sure the the hardware switch for wi-fi is on.

Comment: Well, there is the result of lsmod: http://pastebin.com/07dTBfpV

Comment: not seeing errors.. try `rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: That last code activated me the detection of the available wifi networks, so that's a great advance!, now when I try to connect to my wifi it loads, but after aproximately 30 seconds it says my pc can't connect to the network.
Additional controllers tab persists in blank.
Any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: change modes of wireless network. Some drivers doesn't support certain modes (like `g` or `n`)

Comment: I don't understand... please, can you tell me how can I change wireless network modes?

Comment: You have to configure in router. :(. I would advice you to open a thread in ubuntuforums also.

Comment: I almost created a new thread in ubuntuforums, but my wifi goes well now. That was: I entered the wifi configuration through a browser and I saw my wifi key was encrypted as WPA-PSK, I changed it to WPA2-PSK and it worked. The strange thing is that after all that I went to "edit network connections" in Ubuntu and I saw that the wifi password was marked as "personal WPA WPA2". I don't know why didn't worked before if Ubuntu accepts "WPA and WPA2". Anyways, thank you much for your interest solving my question, Web-E. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered the wifi configuration through a browser and I saw my wifi key was encrypted as WPA-PSK, I changed it to WPA2-PSK and wifi worked.